# Advertising on Amazon Kindle

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

For some reason today, I had a thought that might be interesting. Would it be worth it to advertize this site on the [Special Offers Amazon Kindle](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004HFS6Z0/ref=as_li_ss_til?tag=httpwwwpearso-20&camp=213381&creative=390973&linkCode=as4&creativeASIN=B004HFS6Z0&adid=1FGMZVAXG96TY02YA260&)? I did a bit of poking around, and found a [guide to all ads](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AdvertisingSite/pdfs/AmazonKSOAdStyleGuide.pdf). It seems like if there was a way to restrict it to people interesting in SFF, which should be easy to do, it might provide a high return on users compared to other methods. Just a thought.

Comment: this is a very neat idea to investigate, at least!

Comment: Does anyone know anyone with this version of the Kindle? Do they pay any attention to these ads at all? (Not suggesting they don't, just wondering if anyone has first/second hand knowledge).

Comment: If we can't target just people interested SFF/Fantasy, this could be a useful joint venture with Literature and/or English.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention @Pearsonartphoto ! I've contacted Amazon and will keep everyone updated on the progress. This is a great idea and I hope it works out.

Comment: @BrettWhite Did you find out what Amazon's procedure is?